# child div getting overlapped

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have 2 divs placed next to each other. First div is given a fixed width of 260px and second div takes up the remaining width. (See below structure)

```
+------------+------------------------------+
|width=260px |  Takes Up Remaining width    |
|  [div A]   |         [div B]              |
|            |                              |
|            |                              |
|            |                              |
|            |                              |
+------------+------------------------------+
```

div A has child divs which are conditionally visible and are larger in width(500px).
These child div is getting overlapped partially by 'div B'.

I have no clues how to avoid child divs of A getting overlapped by div B.

Note: played bit with Z index but doesn't help.

Please suggest some solution.

**EDIT :**
 Below is the code snippet.

```
<div id="DIV-A" style="position: absolute; width: 260px; overflow: auto;  box-sizing: border-box;>
   <div id="childDiv" style="position: absolute; width: 500px; 150px ;z-index:1000>

   </div>

</div>    

<div id="DIV-B" style="position: absolute; left: 260px;  width: 1420px; box-sizing: border-box;"></div>
```

Comment: [`overflow-x`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow-x).

Comment: You have set width of parent div A 260px and child of it is of 500px, so it is as it should be. What you exactly want?

Comment: @Vipul, child div should overlap div B. Currently Div B is overlapping some part of child div (child of Div A)

Comment: Conditionally visible make me think of using overflow hidden or overflow scroll. But without looking at your html or a fiddle it's not easy to say

Comment: Added code snippet to question. Please check again.

Answer (score 2):

CSS part

```
 #div_a
    {
        background-color:Green;
        position:relative;
        width:260px;
        height:500px;
        float:left;
    }
    #div_b
    {

        background-color:Gray;
        height:500px;


    }

    .div_a_child
    {

        width:500px;
        position:absolute;

        background-color:Black;
        height:300px;
        color:White;
    }
```

and the HTML tags

```
<div id=div_a>

    <div class=div_a_child>
       Child of Div A
    </div>

</div>

<div id=div_b>

</div>
```

This is done before editing question!!

Just saw your updates in question!!

Don't use "Absolute" position for div!
if you really want to use, place it within div with position "relative"
Changes made in your code is below!

```
 <div id="DIV-A" style="position:relative; width:260px;  height:500px; background-color:Yellow;float:left;">
       <div id="childDiv" style="position:absolute; width:500px; height:300px; background-color:Green;">

       </div>

</div>    

<div id="DIV-B" style=" background-color:Silver; height:500px; ">

</div>
```

And please avoid inline CSS! place CSS codes in seperate file!

Hope it was helpful!
Happy Coding! :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should play a little with "position:absolute" and "position:relative" as CSS-Attributes for the childelement.

Explanation: The child element cant have a greater width than its parent element if its in the "flow". With the "position" attribute you can take it out of the normal "flow", so it could be wider.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NqXYKb

```
#child { 
  width: 500px;
  height: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: yellow;
  position: relative;
}
```